# Show that the triangles are congruent

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $\triangle ABC$ be a acute-angled triangle so that $AB>AC$ and $\angle BAC = 60^\circ$. Let $O$ be the circumcenter and $H$ the orthocenter. Let $OH$ intersect $AB$ and $AC$ in $P$ and $Q$ respectively. Show that $AQ=AP$.
Or alternatively, show that $\angle AOP$ and/or $\angle AHQ$ equal $\angle ACB+90-\angle BAC$

I know $BAO=CAH=90-\angle ACB$, but that's all I've got. I need one of two above.
An elementary solution is preferred.

Comment: As $AH= 2R\cos A$, in this case $\cos A=\frac12$, so $AH=AO$. The other angles at the vertex are easily proven equal, so $\triangle APO \cong \triangle AQH$.  Simple :D

Comment: Did you know that thing, $AH= 2R\cos A$? Otherwise we would have to think of a geometric proof that $AH=AO$. :D

Comment: No where does that come from?

Comment: Hmm, let CH cut AB at D. Then, $AD= b\cos A$. So, $AH= \frac{AD}{\sin B} =   2R\cos A$, by sine rule. Do you follow? :D

Comment: Yes. It's not exactly elementary, though.

Comment: You can do it using similarity as well, if you wish to avoid trig :)

Comment: if you wish to post an answer, please do so :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Construction: CH is produced to cut the circumference at X. BX, when joined, cuts QP produced at M.

The pink angles are all $30^0$.

OM is the perpendicular bisector of BX. This makes the angles marked red are all equal to $30^0$.

The above is sufficient to say $\angle AQH = \angle APQ = 60^0$

Comment: Is $OM$ the perpendicular bisector of $BX$ because $|OX|=|OB|$ and $|HX|=|HB$| so $H$ and $O$ lie on the perpendicular bisector of $BX$?

Comment: @wowlolbrommer By “angles in the same segment”, $\angle X = \angle BAC = 60^0$. This makes ⊿HXB equilateral. Therefore, |HX|=|HB|. Together with your finding, also HO being the common side, we can say that ⊿HXO is congruent to ⊿HBO. This further means $\angle XHM = \angle BHM$. A step further means |XM| = |MB| and $\angle XMH = \angle BMH = 90^0$. Sorry for making a big jump.

Comment: ok thanks for your solution!

Answer (score 0):

The length of $AH$ in any $\triangle ABC$ is given by $2R\cos A$, and can be proven rather easily using the sine rule. Thus, in this case $\cos A=\frac12$, thus $AH =OH$. Hence, $\angle POA=\angle QHA$.

Of course, $\angle OAP = \angle OAB = 90^{\circ}-\angle C=\angle HAC = \angle HAQ$. Thus, by virtue of ASA criterion, $\triangle APO \cong \triangle AQH$.

Comment: But you're still using trig

Comment: Ah .. let me think of a solution using similarity.

Comment: It's alright otherwise :)